# How to evaluate the following integral?

Tags: definite-integrals

How do I evaluate the following expression?

$$\int_1^3\frac{1+x}{1+x^3}~\mathrm{d}x$$

I am trying this question by integrating the expressions separately like $\frac{1}{1+x^3}$ and $\frac{x}{1+x^3}$. But can't solve after that. How to proceed further?

Comment: Hint : $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$

Complete the square in the denominator and compare with the general forms of integral.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to evaluate the following integral $\int \frac{1}{x^2-x+1} dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932568/how-to-evaluate-the-following-integral-int-frac1x2-x1-dx)

Comment: @Ercanayan I don't understand why your (now self-deleted) answer was downvoted. May be someone deemed the OP did not give enough "context"? (i.e. show enough effort)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

\begin{align*}
\frac{1+x}{1+x^3}
&=\frac{1+x}{(1+x)(x^2-x+1)} \\
&=\frac{1}{x^2-x+1} \\
&=\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}+1} \\
&=\frac{4}{3\left(\left(\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1\right)},
\end{align*}

so that we, with the substitution $\xi=\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}$, $\mathrm{d}\xi=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}~\mathrm{d}x$, get that

\begin{align*}
\int_1^3\frac{1+x}{1+x^3}~\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{\mathrm{d}\xi}{\xi^2+1} \\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\biggl[\arctan\xi\biggr]_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}} \\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\arctan\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}-\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Or stop at the second $=$ and apply the proposed duplicate.